# Difference between P(A,B) vs P(A∩C) vs P(A.B) vs P(AB)

Tags: probability, notation

- P(A,B)
- P(A∩B)
- P(A.B)
- P(AB)

Above 4 statements looks almost similar to me. Can anybody define if there is any difference between above 4 and compare them in detail.

Comment: one of them uses a C

Comment: I am not familiar with $P(A.B)$. The others (if you replace $C$ by $B$) stand - as far as I know - all for the probability of event "$A$ and $B$". I might be wrong about $P(A,B)$.

Comment: Sorry guys. A mistake. I changed P(A∩C) to P(A∩B)

Comment: @drhab I didn't get u. What are the similar ones and non-similar ones

Comment: I am saying that in my view there is no essential difference between the expressions, but that I could be wrong in this. $P(A.B)$ is, as said, not within my scope.

Comment: Ok. thanks a lot

Comment: To back up @drhab , I've also seen $A,B$ and $A\cap B$ and $AB$ and understand them all to mean "$A$ and $B$". I've not seen $A.B$ before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$A \cap B$ is often abbreviated to $AB.\;$ I also, am unfamiliar with $A.B$, but I suspect you may mean $A\cdot B$, which would be equivalent to the other two.

Then comma notation is very common with events involving random variables. For example $P(X \le 3, Y > 2)$ is common shorthand
for $P(\{X \le 3\}\cap \{Y > 2\}).$ I have not seen it used just
for letters as in $P(A,B),\,$ except for consistency in a discussion of random variables.

In summary, I think they are all the same, with the possible
exception of the one with the dot in period position.

Notes:

(a) In older books, you may find $A + B$ as an abbreviation for $A \cup B$, and more recently, as an abbreviation for "$A \cup B$ where $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive". 
So that $P(A + B) = P(A) + P(B)$ as in Kolmogorov's axiom, without
elaboration.
But $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(AB)$ is a theorem. 
Whenever you see $+$ between sets, you need to check the
context very carefully.

(b) The use of $AB$
for $A \cap B$ can avoid parentheses in expressions such
as $AB \cup CD = (A\cap B) \cup (C\cap D),$ because one takes
it for granted that $\cap$ written as a 'product' precedes $\cup$ in the order of set-theoretic operations.